# How do i find some text and symbols in string python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

I need some help figuring out how to find `TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): routing change (80)`

From this lot....

```
Loaded CEC from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cec.so
Callback added
CEC has cec_adapter_descriptor
Initializing CEC library
CEC Log message: Broadcast (F): osd name set to 'Broadcast'
CEC Log message: connection opened, clearing any previous input and waiting for active transmissions to end before starting
CEC Log message: communication thread started
CEC Log message: turning controlled mode on
CEC Log message: communication thread ended
CEC Log message: connection opened
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - trying to get the physical address via ADL
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - ADL returned physical address 0000
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - trying to get the physical address via nvidia driver
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - nvidia driver returned physical address 0000
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - trying to get the physical address via drm files
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - drm files returned physical address 0000
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - trying to get the physical address from the OS
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - OS returned physical address 0000
CEC Log message: unregistering all CEC clients
CEC Log message: connection opened, clearing any previous input and waiting for active transmissions to end before starting
CEC Log message: communication thread started
CEC Log message: turning controlled mode on
CEC Log message: connection opened
CEC Log message: << Broadcast (F) -> TV (0): POLL
CEC Log message: << f0
CEC Log message: processor thread started
CEC Log message: setting the line timeout to 3
CEC Log message: >> POLL sent
CEC Log message: TV (0): device status changed into 'present'
CEC Log message: << requesting vendor ID of 'TV' (0)
CEC Log message: << f0:8c
CEC Log message: >> 0f:00:8c:04
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '\x8c\x04', 'ack': True, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 15, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 0},)
CEC Log message: marking opcode 'give device vendor id' as unsupported feature for device 'TV'
CEC Log message: expected response received (87: device vendor id)
CEC Log message: registering new CEC client - v4.0.4
CEC Log message: detecting logical address for type 'recording device'
CEC Log message: trying logical address 'Recorder 1'
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> Recorder 1 (1): POLL
CEC Log message: << 11
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): feature abort ( 0)
CEC Log message: CEC transmission - received response - TRANSMIT_FAILED_ACK
CEC Log message: << 11
CEC Log message: CEC transmission - received response - TRANSMIT_FAILED_ACK
CEC Log message: >> POLL not sent
CEC Log message: using logical address 'Recorder 1'
CEC Log message: Recorder 1 (1): device status changed into 'handled by libCEC'
CEC Log message: Recorder 1 (1): power status changed from 'unknown' to 'on'
CEC Log message: Recorder 1 (1): vendor = Pulse Eight (001582)
CEC Log message: Recorder 1 (1): CEC version 1.4
CEC Log message: AllocateLogicalAddresses - device '0', type 'recording device', LA '1'
CEC Log message: setting ackmask to  2
CEC Log message: Recorder 1 (1): osd name set to 'python-cec'
CEC Log message: Recorder 1 (1): menu language set to 'eng'
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - trying to get the physical address via ADL
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - ADL returned physical address 0000
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - trying to get the physical address via nvidia driver
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - nvidia driver returned physical address 0000
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - trying to get the physical address via drm files
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - drm files returned physical address 0000
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - trying to get the physical address from the OS
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - OS returned physical address 0000
CEC Log message: setting HDMI port to 1 on device TV (0)
CEC Log message: Recorder 1 (1): physical address changed from ffff to 1000
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> broadcast (F): physical address 1000
CEC Log message: << 1f:84:10:00:01
CEC Log message: using persisted autonomous mode setting: 'enabled'
CEC Log message: using persisted CEC version setting: '1.4'
CEC Log message: using persisted logical address setting: 'Recorder 1'
CEC Log message: >> 01:46
CEC Log message: using persisted device type setting: 'recording device'
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '', 'ack': False, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 1, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 70},)
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): OSD name 'python-cec'
CEC Log message: << 10:47:70:79:74:68:6f:6e:2d:63:65:63
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): give osd name (46)
CEC Log message: using persisted logical address mask setting: '206'
CEC Log message: using persisted physical address setting: '1000'
CEC Log message: CEC client registered: libCEC version = 4.0.4, client version = 4.0.4, firmware version = 9, firmware build date: Fri Nov  2 10:08:56 2018 +0000, logical address(es) = Recorder 1 (1) , base device: TV (0), HDMI port number: 1, physical address: 1.0.0.0, compiled on Linux-4.4.0-161-generic ... , features: P8_USB, DRM, P8_detect, randr, Exynos, AOCEC
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): OSD name 'python-cec'
CEC Log message: << 10:47:70:79:74:68:6f:6e:2d:63:65:63
CEC Log message: << requesting power status of 'TV' (0)
CEC Log message: << 10:8f
CEC Log message: RECEIVE_FAILED
Creating Device object for TV
CEC Log message: >> 01:90:00
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '\x00', 'ack': False, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 1, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 144},)
CEC Log message: TV (0): power status changed from 'unknown' to 'on'
CEC Log message: expected response received (90: report power status)
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): report power status (90)
CEC Log message: >> 01:46
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '', 'ack': False, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 1, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 70},)
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): OSD name 'python-cec'
CEC Log message: << 10:47:70:79:74:68:6f:6e:2d:63:65:63
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): give osd name (46)
CEC Log message: >> 06
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Tuner 2 (6)
CEC Log message: >> 06
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Tuner 2 (6)
CEC Log message: >> 07
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Tuner 3 (7)
CEC Log message: >> 07
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Tuner 3 (7)
CEC Log message: >> 08
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Playback 2 (8)
CEC Log message: >> 08
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Playback 2 (8)
CEC Log message: >> 09
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Recorder 3 (9)
CEC Log message: >> 09
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Recorder 3 (9)
CEC Log message: >> 0f:80:30:00:30:00
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '0\x000\x00', 'ack': True, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 15, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 128},)
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): routing change (80)
CEC Log message: >> 0f:86:30:00
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '0\x00', 'ack': True, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 15, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 134},)
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) sets stream path to physical address 3000
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): set stream path (86)
CEC Log message: >> 0a
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Tuner 4 (a)
CEC Log message: >> 0a
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Tuner 4 (a)
CEC Log message: >> 0b
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Playback 3 (b)
CEC Log message: >> 0b
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Playback 3 (b)
CEC Log message: >> 0f:80:10:00:10:00
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '\x10\x00\x10\x00', 'ack': True, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 15, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 128},)
CEC Log message: making Recorder 1 (1) the active source
CEC Log message: marking the adapter as active source
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): routing change (80)
CEC Log message: >> source activated: Recorder 1 (1)
Got event 64 with data (True, 1)
CEC Log message: sending active source message for 'Recorder 1'
CEC Log message: << requesting vendor ID of 'TV' (0)
CEC Log message: 'give device vendor id' is marked as unsupported feature for device 'TV'
CEC Log message: << powering on 'TV' (0)
CEC Log message: << 10:04
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> broadcast (F): active source (1000)
CEC Log message: << 1f:82:10:00
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): menu state 'activated'
CEC Log message: << 10:8e:00
CEC Log message: >> 0f:86:10:00
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '\x10\x00', 'ack': True, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 15, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 134},)
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) sets stream path to physical address 1000
CEC Log message: Recorder 1 (1) was already marked as active source
CEC Log message: >> source activated: Recorder 1 (1)
Got event 64 with data (True, 1)
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> broadcast (F): active source (1000)
CEC Log message: << 1f:82:10:00
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): set stream path (86)
CEC Log message: >> 01:46
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '', 'ack': False, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 1, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 70},)
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): OSD name 'python-cec'
CEC Log message: << 10:47:70:79:74:68:6f:6e:2d:63:65:63
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): give osd name (46)
CEC Log message: >> 01:8d:02
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '\x02', 'ack': False, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 1, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 141},)
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): menu state 'activated'
CEC Log message: << 10:8e:00
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): menu request (8D)
CEC Log message: >> 01:46
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '', 'ack': False, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 1, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 70},)
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): OSD name 'python-cec'
CEC Log message: << 10:47:70:79:74:68:6f:6e:2d:63:65:63
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): give osd name (46)
CEC Log message: >> 01:8d:02
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '\x02', 'ack': False, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 1, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 141},)
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): menu state 'activated'
CEC Log message: << 10:8e:00
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): menu request (8D)
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/Python works/event-test.py", line 31, in <module>
    while True:
KeyboardInterrupt
```

this is code snipped from my project.

```
def cb(event, *args):
    print("Got event", event, "with data", args)
def log_cb(event, level, time, message):
    print("CEC Log message:", message)
```

I made this but it doesn't work.

```
while True:
    if "routing change(80)" in '$log_cb':
        print("it worked     ")

#    if (cb == "___routing change(80) "):
#        print("it worked     ")
```

-------------------------------------------------- update ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
After Tom Robinson gave me a pointer in the right direction
here is the full code, the error i'm receiving is as he said but now I cannot fathom what arguments for event, level, time and message are needed
I've tried a few print commands to see if i can get the right info.
also tried `if "routing change(80)" in log_cb(event, level, time, message):` but get `NameError: name 'event' is not defined`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Callback test; just to see if callbacks are working.

from __future__ import print_function
from time import sleep
import cec

print("Loaded CEC from", cec.__file__)

def cb(event, *args):
    print("Got event", event, "with data", args)

# arguments: iils
def log_cb(event, level, time, message):
    print("CEC Log message:", message)

cec.add_callback(cb, cec.EVENT_ALL & ~cec.EVENT_LOG)
cec.add_callback(log_cb, cec.EVENT_LOG)
print("Callback added")
sleep(2)

if cec.HAVE_CEC_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTOR:
    print("CEC has cec_adapter_descriptor");
else:
    print("CEC does not have cec_adapter_descriptor");

print("Initializing CEC library")
cec.init()

print("Creating Device object for TV")
while True:
#    if "routing change(80)" in "log_cb":

    if "routing change(80)" in log_cb():
        print("it worked     ")
```

And the new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/Python works/event-test.py", line 32, in <module>
    if "routing change(80)" in log_cb():
TypeError: log_cb() takes exactly 4 arguments (0 given)
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '\x00', 'ack': False, 'opcode_set'
```

---

code update:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Callback test; just to see if callbacks are working.

from __future__ import print_function
from time import sleep
import cec

print("Loaded CEC from", cec.__file__)

def cb(event, *args):
    print("Got event", event, "with data", args)

# arguments: iils
def log_cb(event, level, time, message):
    print("CEC Log message:", message)

    if "routing change (80)" in message:        
        exit()
#        print("it worked     ")
#   if (message == "routing change(80)"):
#       exit()

cec.add_callback(cb, cec.EVENT_ALL & ~cec.EVENT_LOG)
cec.add_callback(log_cb, cec.EVENT_LOG)
print("Callback added")
sleep(2)

if cec.HAVE_CEC_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTOR:
    print("CEC has cec_adapter_descriptor");
else:
    print("CEC does not have cec_adapter_descriptor");

print("Initializing CEC library")
cec.init()

print("Creating Device object for TV")
print(cb)
print(log_cb)

#sleep(22)

while True:
    pass
```

that `while true` is only there for testing as without it the script ends at `line print(log_cb)` 
I'm running it from CLI

Log message:

```
Loaded CEC from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cec.so
Callback added
CEC has cec_adapter_descriptor
Initializing CEC library
CEC Log message: Broadcast (F): osd name set to 'Broadcast'
CEC Log message: connection opened, clearing any previous input and waiting for active transmissions to end before starting
CEC Log message: communication thread started
CEC Log message: turning controlled mode on
CEC Log message: communication thread ended
CEC Log message: connection opened
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - trying to get the physical address via ADL
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - ADL returned physical address 0000
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - trying to get the physical address via nvidia driver
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - nvidia driver returned physical address 0000
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - trying to get the physical address via drm files
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - drm files returned physical address 0000
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - trying to get the physical address from the OS
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - OS returned physical address 0000
CEC Log message: unregistering all CEC clients
CEC Log message: connection opened, clearing any previous input and waiting for active transmissions to end before starting
CEC Log message: communication thread started
CEC Log message: turning controlled mode on
CEC Log message: connection opened
CEC Log message: << Broadcast (F) -> TV (0): POLL
CEC Log message: << f0
CEC Log message: processor thread started
CEC Log message: setting the line timeout to 3
CEC Log message: >> POLL sent
CEC Log message: TV (0): device status changed into 'present'
CEC Log message: << requesting vendor ID of 'TV' (0)
CEC Log message: << f0:8c
CEC Log message: >> 0f:00:8c:04
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '\x8c\x04', 'ack': True, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 15, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 0},)
CEC Log message: marking opcode 'give device vendor id' as unsupported feature for device 'TV'
CEC Log message: expected response received (87: device vendor id)
CEC Log message: registering new CEC client - v4.0.4
CEC Log message: detecting logical address for type 'recording device'
CEC Log message: trying logical address 'Recorder 1'
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> Recorder 1 (1): POLL
CEC Log message: << 11
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): feature abort ( 0)
CEC Log message: CEC transmission - received response - TRANSMIT_FAILED_ACK
CEC Log message: << 11
CEC Log message: CEC transmission - received response - TRANSMIT_FAILED_ACK
CEC Log message: >> POLL not sent
CEC Log message: using logical address 'Recorder 1'
CEC Log message: Recorder 1 (1): device status changed into 'handled by libCEC'
CEC Log message: Recorder 1 (1): power status changed from 'unknown' to 'on'
CEC Log message: Recorder 1 (1): vendor = Pulse Eight (001582)
CEC Log message: Recorder 1 (1): CEC version 1.4
CEC Log message: AllocateLogicalAddresses - device '0', type 'recording device', LA '1'
CEC Log message: setting ackmask to  2
CEC Log message: Recorder 1 (1): osd name set to 'python-cec'
CEC Log message: Recorder 1 (1): menu language set to 'eng'
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - trying to get the physical address via ADL
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - ADL returned physical address 0000
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - trying to get the physical address via nvidia driver
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - nvidia driver returned physical address 0000
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - trying to get the physical address via drm files
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - drm files returned physical address 0000
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - trying to get the physical address from the OS
CEC Log message: GetPhysicalAddress - OS returned physical address 0000
CEC Log message: setting HDMI port to 1 on device TV (0)
CEC Log message: Recorder 1 (1): physical address changed from ffff to 1000
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> broadcast (F): physical address 1000
CEC Log message: << 1f:84:10:00:01
CEC Log message: using persisted autonomous mode setting: 'enabled'
CEC Log message: using persisted CEC version setting: '1.4'
CEC Log message: using persisted logical address setting: 'Recorder 1'
CEC Log message: using persisted device type setting: 'recording device'
CEC Log message: >> 01:46
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '', 'ack': False, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 1, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 70},)
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): OSD name 'python-cec'
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): give osd name (46)
CEC Log message: << 10:47:70:79:74:68:6f:6e:2d:63:65:63
CEC Log message: using persisted logical address mask setting: '206'
CEC Log message: using persisted physical address setting: '1000'
CEC Log message: CEC client registered: libCEC version = 4.0.4, client version = 4.0.4, firmware version = 9, firmware build date: Fri Nov  2 10:08:56 2018 +0000, logical address(es) = Recorder 1 (1) , base device: TV (0), HDMI port number: 1, physical address: 1.0.0.0, compiled on Linux-4.4.0-161-generic ... , features: P8_USB, DRM, P8_detect, randr, Exynos, AOCEC
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): OSD name 'python-cec'
CEC Log message: << 10:47:70:79:74:68:6f:6e:2d:63:65:63
CEC Log message: << requesting power status of 'TV' (0)
CEC Log message: << 10:8f
CEC Log message: RECEIVE_FAILED
CEC Log message: >> 01:90:00Creating Device object for TV

Got event 4<function cb at 0x7f61ce15e2d0>
 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '\x00', 'ack': False, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 1, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 144},)
CEC Log message: TV (0): power status changed from 'unknown' to 'on'
CEC Log message: expected response received (90: report power status)
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): report power status (90)
<function log_cb at 0x7f61ce15e250>
CEC Log message: >> 01:46
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '', 'ack': False, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 1, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 70},)
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): OSD name 'python-cec'
CEC Log message: << 10:47:70:79:74:68:6f:6e:2d:63:65:63
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): give osd name (46)
CEC Log message: >> 0e
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Free use (e)
CEC Log message: >> 0e
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Free use (e)
CEC Log message: >> 0f:80:30:00:30:00
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '0\x000\x00', 'ack': True, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 15, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 128},)
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): routing change (80)
CEC Log message: >> 0f:86:30:00
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '0\x00', 'ack': True, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 15, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 134},)
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) sets stream path to physical address 3000
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): set stream path (86)
CEC Log message: >> 01
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1)
CEC Log message: >> 0f:80:10:00:10:00
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '\x10\x00\x10\x00', 'ack': True, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 15, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 128},)
CEC Log message: making Recorder 1 (1) the active source
CEC Log message: marking the adapter as active source
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): routing change (80)
CEC Log message: >> source activated: Recorder 1 (1)
Got event 64 with data (True, 1)
CEC Log message: sending active source message for 'Recorder 1'
CEC Log message: << requesting vendor ID of 'TV' (0)
CEC Log message: 'give device vendor id' is marked as unsupported feature for device 'TV'
CEC Log message: << powering on 'TV' (0)
CEC Log message: << 10:04
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> broadcast (F): active source (1000)
CEC Log message: << 1f:82:10:00
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): menu state 'activated'
CEC Log message: << 10:8e:00
CEC Log message: >> 0f:86:10:00
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '\x10\x00', 'ack': True, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 15, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 134},)
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) sets stream path to physical address 1000
CEC Log message: Recorder 1 (1) was already marked as active source
CEC Log message: >> source activated: Recorder 1 (1)
Got event 64 with data (True, 1)
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> broadcast (F): active source (1000)
CEC Log message: << 1f:82:10:00
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): set stream path (86)
CEC Log message: >> 01:46
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '', 'ack': False, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 1, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 70},)
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): OSD name 'python-cec'
CEC Log message: << 10:47:70:79:74:68:6f:6e:2d:63:65:63
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): give osd name (46)
CEC Log message: >> 01:8d:02
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '\x02', 'ack': False, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 1, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 141},)
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): menu state 'activated'
CEC Log message: << 10:8e:00
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): menu request (8D)
CEC Log message: >> 01:46
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '', 'ack': False, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 1, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 70},)
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): OSD name 'python-cec'
CEC Log message: << 10:47:70:79:74:68:6f:6e:2d:63:65:63
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): give osd name (46)
CEC Log message: >> 01:8d:02
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '\x02', 'ack': False, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 1, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 141},)
CEC Log message: << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): menu state 'activated'
CEC Log message: << 10:8e:00
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): menu request (8D)
CEC Log message: >> 03
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Tuner 1 (3)
CEC Log message: >> 03
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Tuner 1 (3)
CEC Log message: >> 04
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Playback 1 (4)
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/Python works/event-test.py", line 42, in <module>
    while True:
KeyboardInterrupt
```

### It should stop as soon as it sees the request change but it doesn't. arrrrggg

last update I tried a few different things after someone suggested `print(message)`so I tried this but I think the `0f:86:30:00` needs to be written in different format and have no idea how to to do that.

```
def log_cb(event, level, time, message):
    print("CEC Log message:", message)
    print(message)

    if '0f:86:30:00' in message:       
        exit()
```

log message snipped with few lines ether side of the event :

```
CEC Log message: << POLL: TV (0) -> Recorder 2 (2)
CEC Log message: >> 0f:80:30:00:30:00
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '0\x000\x00', 'ack': True, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 15, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 128},)
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): routing change (80)
CEC Log message: >> 0f:86:30:00
Got event 4 with data ({'initiator': 0, 'parameters': '0\x00', 'ack': True, 'opcode_set': True, 'destination': 15, 'eom': True, 'transmit_timeout': 1000, 'opcode': 134},)
CEC Log message: >> TV (0) sets stream path to physical address 3000
```

Comment: `if "routing change(80)" in '$log_cb':` is always false. Maybe you meant `$log_cb` without quotes? Otherwise, it's a string literal, not a variable. And `$` is illegal in a variable name, so it's uncertain what to make of this without more information.

Comment: No its not always False.
Its from a stream of data that comes from my TV via CEC.
And that only shows up when my TV changes sources. 
I cannot use the CEC Function as my TV reports back the same data despite the source.
So i found a way to detect it with this line 'TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): routing change (80)'

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm being clear.... `if "routing change(80)" in '$log_cb':` is asking whether the string `"routing change(80)"` exists as a substring of another string `"$log_cb"`. Of course it doesn't and it never will. The statement is always false as much as `if "foobar" in "bazquux"` is always false.

Comment: What ???
Please re-read my OP. or
I want python to do something when this is output in the log i provided appears.

Comment: It seems you may be coming from another language to Python. Run the interactive console and type `'e' in 'hello'` – it should say `True`. Now type `'o' in "$hello"` – also `True`. Both single *and* double quotes can be used to delimit strings; `$` means nothing for Python. So @ggorlen is right. Please *explain in words* what you *believe* your statement would do.

Answer (score 1):

`log_cb` is a callback you provide to the `cec` module with `cec.add_callback(log_cb, cec.EVENT_LOG)`. This is clearly a logging handler that `cec` calls automatically on certain events; it's not something that makes sense for you to call yourself. This handler seems working since you've shown the output from its print statement.

`message` contains the substring you're interested in, so move your substring check into `log_cb` and get rid of the `while True:` block which will (probably) freeze your program (I'm not familiar with the `cec` library, but it seems like the wrong way to keep the program alive to poll for events and I don't see it mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/trainman419/python-cec)):

```
def log_cb(event, level, time, message):
    print("CEC Log message:", message)

    if "routing change (80)" in message:
        print("routing change (80) was in the message")
```

Note that the line `if "routing change (80)" in '$log_cb':` is nonsensical because it's always false. `'$log_cb'` is a string literal, not a variable holding a value like you may think.

In your updated code:

```
if (message == "routing change(80)"):
```

There are two problems:

1. The real substring in the log you posted is `"routing change (80)"`, not `"routing change(80)"` (the space matters).
2. `message == "routing change (80)"` is not the correct logic and will likely never be true based on the log you showed. `"routing change (80)" in message` is the correct logic because it checks whether the desired string is a substring of `message` rather than an exact match.

Comment: Thanks @gorlen if "it's not something that makes sense for you to call yourself." How do i do it??? 
I want to monitor for that specific event 'routing change(80)'
I moved  and changed the if statement but still no luck.
I Originally put `code while: True pass ` as the code would just close after one run.
never the less you are right its code I'm just using for testing to finally put it into my project

Comment: If this doesn't work, please explain what you're seeing. What about it doesn't work--do you see output at all? If so, what? How did you get output that you show in the first place? Don't use any `while True` loop, it'll freeze your program in an infinite loop unless `cec` happens to spawn a separate process. The module you passed the callback into when you register it calls it for you when events fire--clearly, it worked on whatever program you used to capture the output you posted at the top of your question.

Comment: Oh i still cant get it to work....
why is it not working.... 
The routing change shows up in the log but it just isn't picking it up

Comment: Oh, funny, I have a missing space: I used `"routing change(80)"` but the actual substring should be `"routing change (80)"`. Try it again please and let me know if it works. If not, post the line that contains `"routing change"`.

Comment: I've updated the OP for ease of reading. Still doesn't work though

Comment: "Still doesn't work"--are you seeing logs printed, but the conditional isn't triggering? Be specific. Please post the result of `print(message)` for the line you're interested in. Is it still `"CEC Log message: >> TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): routing change (80)"` exactly? If not, please share what it looks like now. If so, then I'm out of ideas I'm afraid. I also recommend `print("it worked")` to be above `exit()`, otherwise it's dead code--the program will exit before it gets a chance to print anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211498/discussion-between-love-to-make-and-ggorlen).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is checking if `"routing change(80)"` is a substring of the string `"$log_cb"`. If you are intending to run the function `log_cb`, you need to call it using log_cb():

```py
while True:
    if "routing change(80)" in log_cb():
        print("it worked     ")
```

You will need to pass arguments for `event`, `level`, `time` and `message`, otherwise you will get a `TypeError`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Tom Robinson i tried your alteration to code. I now have a new error but i feel its a step in the right direction. I will edit original post with update.

Comment: Sorry I missed the last bit but i dont know what arguments to put in there I tried  "if "routing change(80)" in log_cb(event, level, time, message):" but get "NameError: name 'event' is not defined"

Comment: You have to pass in real variables/values into `log_cb` that you've defined. But even then, `log_cb` returns `None` and doesn't use its parameters, so this won't work either.  What you probably want to do is move your substring check into `log_cb` and run it on one of these parameters, probably `message`--it's pretty clear that it's intended to be called by whatever `cec` is, not your own code. Remove `while True`--this doesn't make much sense. I think a basic Python tutorial would go a long way for you.